# Does the Go compiler concatenate strings separated by a plus sign?

Tags: string, go

Let's say I have the following in my code:

```
err := "This is a very long error message"+
    "that spans multiple lines."
```

Will Go compile this under the hood into one string, or is there some small penalty associated with doing the addition there?

Comment: As you may already know, you can also write multi-line strings using the \` character, similar to ''' in Python. http://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a [constant expression](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions) and is specified to be evaluated at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

It's compiled as one string for Go 1.3.

```
go.string."This is a very long error messagethat spans multiple lines."
```

It's probably one string for earlier versions too.